# google maps iOS/android limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a mobile app which will use google maps. Does Google maps for iOS/android maps have usage limits which my app can use? I assume there would be or else couldn't an app that gets popular then make millions of calls to google a day which would be costly I believe for google. I can't find any info on this. Reading other posts I can see a few google map api have a limit of 25000/a day but can't find anything for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understand, you have unlimited access to Google Maps using Android or iOS API. The API key is for tracking purpose only.